# Weird memory usage of looped pandas GroupBy function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, memory-leaks, out-of-memory

I am working on this problem for several hours and can't find a solution. I am running a loop and do some calculations on a relatively big DataFrame. But with every loop, the virtual memory usage increases, until I am running out of memory. I tried manual garbage collection, setting the default thresholds of gc and libraries like pympler and objgraph to find the cause of this behaviour, but haven't been successful.

I created a minimal code example which runs out of memory in a couple of seconds on 8gb of RAM and ~7gb of paging file in a few iterations:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time
import psutil
import os


def some_operations(data):
    data1 = data.groupby(0)[2].shift(-5).rolling(window=5, min_periods=1).max()
    data1 = data.groupby(0)[2].shift(-5).rolling(window=5, min_periods=1).max()
    data1 = data.groupby(0)[2].shift(-5).rolling(window=5, min_periods=1).max()
    data1 = data.groupby(0)[2].shift(-5).rolling(window=5, min_periods=1).max()
    data1 = data.groupby(0)[2].shift(-5).rolling(window=5, min_periods=1).max()
    return data1


if __name__=="__main__":
    data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((7000000, 13)))
    data[0] = data[0] > 0.5
    for j in range(500):
        tack = time.time()
        very_important_variable = some_operations(data)
        p = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
        memory_use = p.memory_info().vms / 1024 ** 2
        tick = time.time()
        print(f"Iteration: {j}, took {tick - tack:.2f} seconds and {memory_use/1000:.2f} GB of memory")
```

Any ideas why this is happening? Memory info tells me, that with every loop there are ~540MB added to the virtual memory.

Thank you so much!

UPDATE:

It seems like Python is not deallocating the groupby actions at `some_operations` properly. Even when I `del data` and `gc.collect()` inside the function, it won't change anything. Found that out by assigning simple variables instead of a groupby function.

How can I REALLY force Python to free up the memory afterwards? del and gc.collect() doesn't seem to work.

Still accumulating memory:

```
def some_operations(data):
    data1 = data.groupby(0)[2].shift(-5).rolling(window=5, min_periods=1).max()
    data2 = data.groupby(0)[2].shift(-5).rolling(window=5, min_periods=1).max()
    data3 = data.groupby(0)[2].shift(-5).rolling(window=5, min_periods=1).max()
    data4 = data.groupby(0)[2].shift(-5).rolling(window=5, min_periods=1).max()
    data5 = data.groupby(0)[2].shift(-5).rolling(window=5, min_periods=1).max()
    result = data1 + data2 + data3 + data4 + data5
    del data1, data2, data3, data4, data5
    gc.collect()
    return result
```

Comment: I think the number of ```data.groupby``` calls may be responsible. Grouping is an "expensive" operation and you use it a few times on a very large dataset. For better performance, the ```pyspark``` package is generally much faster than pandas.

Comment: Thank you, I am trying to test spark then!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the most up-to-date Pandas version resolved this issue. It even halved memory allocation!